# Defining a property in iOS class extension

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, ios5.1

I would like to add a property to UITableView in a Class Extension:

```
@interface UITableViewController ()

@property NSString *entityString;

@end
```

Then I import the extension and then I use entityString property in a subclass of UITableViewController:

```
@implementation CustomerTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.entityString = @"Customer";
    ...
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
...
```

[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW1) says:

> the compiler will automatically synthesize the relevant accessor
>   methods (...) inside the primary class
>   implementation.

But when I try to execute it I get this error:

> -[CustomerTableViewController setEntityString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x737b670

What am I doing wrong? maybe the property cannot be accessed by subclasses?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A *class extension* is used to declare additional interface -- methods and properties -- whose implementation contract will be met within the class's primary `@implementation`.

Which is exactly why you can't add storage -- add ivars -- via a class extension.   A class extension is an interface, no more, no less.   `@synthesize` is what creates storage for `@property` declarations, but `@synthesize` of an `@property` can only appear in the `@implementation` of the class (whether explicitly or as a default behavior of the compiler).

Since you can't recompile the framework class, you can't add ivars to it.

@prashat's answer is one way to add storage to an existing class.   However, going that route is generally undesirable;   hanging state off of framework classes willy-nilly is a sign of poor design and will make your application significantly more difficult to maintain over time.

Far better to revisit your design, understand why you currently require attaching state to an object that can't directly contain it, and refactoring that requirement away.

Comment: Can't ivars being added to class extension or this depends to the compiler used?

Comment: You can declare ivars and properties in class extensions, but the storage for such will not be created unless the extension is seen by the compiler before the compilation of the class's @implementation.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying - i didn't notice alazaro was using a class extension for a framework class actually

Answer (score 17):

Try using a category with Associative References instead. It is much cleaner and will work on all instances of UIButton.

```
UIButton+Property.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface UIButton(Property)

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSObject *property;

@end


UIButton+Property.m

#import "UIButton+Property.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation UIButton(Property)

static char UIB_PROPERTY_KEY;

@dynamic property;

-(void)setProperty:(NSObject *)property
{
  objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &UIB_PROPERTY_KEY, property, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

-(NSObject*)property
{
   return (NSObject*)objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &UIB_PROPERTY_KEY);
}

@end
```

//Example usage

```
#import "UIButton+Property.h"


UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button1.property = @"HELLO";
NSLog(@"Property %@", button1.property);
button1.property = nil;
NSLog(@"Property %@", button1.property);
```

Comment: How are Associative References cleaner than class extensions?

Comment: They are cleaner because they work (the class extension doesn't because the extension wasn't present when the @implementation for the class was compiled), but that doesn't make them clean.   Adding state to existing framework classes is a sign of bad design and high fragility.    While prashant's answer works, doing such is typically a sign that you should reconsider your architecture.

Answer (score 5):

The docs state:

> Class extensions are like anonymous categories, except that the methods they declare must be implemented in the main @implementation block for the corresponding class.

When you use `@property`, it is roughly equivalent to *declaring* accessor methods. So this means you can only do such a thing if you are also the author of the "main" `@implementation` block of the class, which with UITableViewController, you are not.

Your only option here is Categories, which cannot add instance variables.

[The docs link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html), and note the very last line of that page:

> The implementation of the setValue: method must appear within the main @implementation block for the class (you cannot implement it in a category). If this is not the case, the compiler emits a warning that it cannot find a method definition for setValue:.

Comment: I think that is not my case, I am not using an ivar + accessors. However, the compiler doesn't complain about my code. The error is in runtime.

Comment: a `@property` **is** an ivar plus accessors.

Comment: Yes, I know, but the compiler does the work for you. I thought it might add accessors in the main class too, no matter if it belongs to me or not.

Comment: **is** an ivar plus accessors when `@synthesize` is used (which is on be default in the latest compilers), yes....

Comment: I think the docs aren't clear enough, or maybe mistaken, because the compiler is not generating any accessors as it says: "the compiler will automatically synthesize the relevant accessor methods (...) inside the primary class implementation."
The reason must be the UITableViewController is precompiled and cannot add them.

Comment: Agreed;  the documentation should be clearer on this subject.  Please file a bug via http://bugreporter.apple.com/ and post the # here.