# Objective-C - Adding some properties without extending class, is there a way?

Tags: objective-c, properties, extending

Here is the problem :( While I am working with Spritekit nodes I need some settings  to be accessible inside SKSpriteNode, SKLabelNode classes etc... Settings are stored in pretty basic types (string, array, floats).SpriteNode have property "name" but that is not enough for me, I need some array field instead because I have few more settings needed...

Is there a way , somehow, to add those settings to let's say SKNode class so they can be a part of SKSPriteNode and SKLabelNode classes?

I dont want to make NSDictionary field as a member of MyScene (SKScene) class to store all settings in format key->value,because accessing them requires more unnecessary programming logic.

I just want to, create node with settings inside, read those settings directly from that node, and based on settings make an further action.

Comment: You can use Categories https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html

Comment: @Guilherme you can't add properties with a category

Comment: Why not just subclass?

Comment: @ChrisH from what I understood, he'd like to use the same data that the classes already have, but wants to read "all at once". He could make a method that gathers all that information and spit it out in one single object. In the case he does need a new property, yes, Category is not the solution.

Comment: Tnx Guilherme, but I think ChrisH is right about adding properties with Categories...I need my own settings (settings property) within those classes... I asked for other solution because I think it's little "ugly" to subclass all those classes because of one or two fields.

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12252725/defining-a-property-in-ios-class-extension

Comment: @ChrisH You can add properties to a category. What you can't do is add instance variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading your needs correctly, then it sounds like you just want to use the userdata property. Every SKNode has an NSDictionary property called userdata. You just have to initialize it and then add your data.

Answer (score 0):

Subclassing would be the preferred method.

There is something called the decorator pattern but with obj-c it would prob be a lot harder for you.