# What's is wrong by declaring an ivar in class extension?

Tags: ios

Is it better to declare an ivar in a class extension?
Or is it only a developer preference?

Comment: Have you tried it? Does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name suggest it is an extension to the functionality of class. You may add extra behavior to the class using extension. Adding member variables or stored properties have quite a bit problems viz:

1. When it is possible to add data member in extension the original class is not aware of the added data member. This leads to problem of allocation for such members while creating object for such classes.
2. It could also create problem with initialization and de-initialization of data members as these are not known to original init() or deinit() methods.
3. Adding data member may alter the very nature of class in terms of its behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you are unable to add instance variables to class extensions.  This is true for both swift and Obj-C.  See this question: [Defining a property in iOS class extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12252725/defining-a-property-in-ios-class-extension).

If you mean, by adding a iVar to the interface extension:

```
@interface MyClass(){
    MyIvar *ivar
}
```

well, thats a bit of a matter of choice and convenience.  In general you should limit your public interface to a minimal set of properties/methods that allow the user to interact with the class in the way you design/expect.  While your code will work fine using either method, exposing more properties/functions can result in more problems as consuming classes may uses properties/functions in ways unplanned for or unexpected.